# Additivity of linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I always read that a linear transformation $f : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is one that satisfies the 2 properties: $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(c \cdot x) = c \cdot f(x)$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Of course, I don't disagree with this. But doesn't the first property imply the latter? So if you have that $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, you would also have that $f(2x)=f(x)+f(x)=2f(x)$. You could then apply some induction on this to derive that $f(c \cdot x) = c \cdot f(x)$ as above, right?

So my question is(if my way of deriving the latter property from the first is correct): Why do authors always write *both* properties if the additivity property implies the other?

Comment: $c$ is not a positive integer in the definition

Comment: @geetha290krm no but then you could say that for $c=0$, you'd have $f(x-x)=f(x)-f(x)$ and a similar simple modification for negative $c$. Does this violate any logic?

Comment: What do you do for $c=\sqrt 2$, for example?

Comment: Your method will ultimately cover all rational $c$. After that you either have to assume something extra (like continuity of $f$) or you can construct functions that have the first property but not the second. This is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation

Comment: I see. Thanks you guys! Also very nice information you provided, Michal :)

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek do you want to post that as an answer?